# Find max values of 1D arrays that may contain NAN

Tags: python, arrays, max

I am trying to find the maximum value in a 1D array using the `max` function in python. However, these arrays may contain NAN as consequence of missing data (flagged astronomical data). Every time I try to find the max value in the array, it gives me NAN as the maximum value. I was wondering if there is a way to find the maximum real number in the array.

Comment: Can you show us your list? If builtin `max` doesn't work, have you tried `numpy.nanmax`?

Comment: Remove NAN values before using max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the two functions 'min', 'max' in Python are affected by 'nan' values. Something is wrong with your code logic. As tested with both Python 2 and 3, min/max functions give correct output values.

[image]

[image]

There's no code in your question but I can guess out you may misconcept between NAN (not a number value), and "NAN" a string constant. Here's a possible case that 'max' function gives output result as "NAN":

[image]

Comment: I believe "NAN" (string constant) was the issue. Thanks for pointing out :)