# Unexpected output of python3 built-in max for array containing nan

Tags: python-3.x, built-in

When I try to find out the index of the largest element in a list by using the `key` keyword in the python3 built-in function, `max`, I find it doesn't necessarily return the index of the max element.

 For example,

```
array = [float('nan'), 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, float('nan')]
max(range(len(array)), key=lambda i: array[i])
```

The above code yields `0` instead of `2` as expected.

**Seemingly Related Questions**

- [Find max values of 1D arrays that may contain NAN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54687218/11122122)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for `max` (and `min`) works roughly in the following way:

```
def my_max(sequence, key=None, default=None):
    max_value = None 
    max_item = None 
    for item in sequence:
        if key is not None:
            value = key(item)
        else:
            value = item 
        if max_item is None:
            max_item = item 
            max_value = value
        elif value > max_value:
            max_value = value  
            max_item = item 
    if max_item is None:
        if default is None:
            raise ValueError
        return default 
    return max_item
```

The actual source code (in C) can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1729).

The main takeaway here is that on the first iteration, for your given input, `max_item` is set to `0`, and `max_value` is set to `nan`. One important thing to note is that the operations `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, and `==` will always return `False` when a `nan` is involved, as defined by the IEEE 754 floating point standard ([example source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN)). This means that no greater element will ever be found after the first item, and hence `0` is returned.

Comment: Wonderful. This explains why only when the first value of array is `nan` gives unexpected output? Is there any ticket for change in behavior in the future for `max`?

Comment: Yes, this also explains why things only go "wrong" when the first value is `nan`. When the first value is not `nan`, `max_value` and `max_item` are set to "actual" floats (i.e. non-`nan` floats), and any `nan` items will then be ignored, because comparison with `nan` returns `False`. There is an issue in the CPython github repo about either changing the behaviour or adding special key functions for `nan`, although it has been inactive for a while: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88536